# problem with shared memory in python not getting into function

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So I have arg parse where it calls the file.py
in it, I have a parent function that makes children using multiprocessing process
I have shared memory in the beginning, but it doesn't get access.

This is not really the code, too many lines but I think this is not a coding problem

Seed of my problem, For some reason, even though I have an array of shared memory this one cannot be found in the function temp giving the error NameError: name 'arr1' is not defined on line arr1.value[0] += 1

p is what makes mores processes.

I think it may be because of the reading of the file by the argparse.
Any ideas?

Comment: What language is this? Python doesn't have a "function" keyword.

Comment: true, my bad fixed

Comment: How about writing a small working program focused just on your problem. You have a `main` with default arguments that you don't use in the example, so don't have them. You create a subprocess with `listFile`, but its not defined. And its not used, so why have it there? You've got `Array`... but what is it? How was it really created in your working program. In your exampke, `arr1` will exist in the subprocess, so your code is doing something different than what we see.

Comment: try it now why, is the shared memory not working on temp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the documentation show `arr1` created in the main thread and then passed as an argument to each of these processes.  You don't want it created in each process.

So you would want something like:

```
imports.....

function temp(listFile, a, c, l, arr1):
   arr1[0] += 1

function main1(files = args.f, a = args.a, c = args.c, l = args.l, p = args.p):
    arr1 = Array("i", args.p)
    newP = Process(target=temp, args = (listFile, a, c, l, arr1))
    newP.start()
    newP.join() 
    # arr1[0] should now be 1.
```

---

One commenter notes that they prefer the creation of shared memory at top level.  In that case you should move the `arr1 = ...` to be under the `if __name__ == '__main__'`.  The important thing is that the shared memory be created once by the main thread.

Comment: I don't think you can create shared memory within a function :/

Comment: @brt: It should either be created in your `if __name__ == '__main__':` or inside your `main()` function which is only called from there.  The important thing is that it is only created once, and only created in your main thread.  Will add a comment.

Comment: it will not work as well, Could I send you some file for you to try it out?

Comment: Okay.  I just realized your code had some other errors in it, too.  I just copied your code to show the important point, without first checking that it worked.  Fixing code, now.